# Android UI: Can I make game-like UI using material design

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I wondering can i make the game-like UI like lego boost app using just material design (set of icon, assets combine with ImageButton, RecyclerView)

[image: Lego boost UI]

Comment: The UI could be done with it, but I think main game may be problem to implement only with default Android controls. You should try custom View with custom Android controls.

Comment: Hi Denny thanks for your reply, I already have the custom View for main game, I just consider the UI, for example with 3 button start,stop, config + button background in top right corner. How can I implement it ? 3 ImageButton + ImageView is ok ?

Comment: Yee, all in RelativeLayout to set proper position on the screen. Layout will be above the main view. Should be good :D

Comment: Thanks danny i will try this.

Comment: It is complex to build this type of UI in Android Studio, that's why Unity & Cocos are used by game developers. It is easy to work with animation, transactions in Unity or Cocos rather than Android Studio.